# How to use knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Im new to javascript, and i tried a simple script, but its not working

I have an index.html file:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
Test
</title>
<script src="js/knockout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p><span data-bind="text adat"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var viewModel = {
adat : "ASD"
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

But its not work, its not showing anything...
I tried to use knockout js in spring mvc project but intellij idea told be
ko is an unresolved type
What is the problem?

Comment: download knockout.js and put it in the js dir?

Comment: yes konckout.js in js dir

Comment: in spring mvc project i got for the ko.applyBindings(viewModel); line this message: unredolved function or method applyBindings()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/ check this basic one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to world of scripting and you done some basic error there

Binding is wrongly given just missed `:` between text and observable

**View :**

```
<title>
Test
</title>
<body>
<p><span data-bind="text:adat"></span></p>
</body>
```

**View Model :**

```
// Here's my data model
var viewModel = function(){
this.adat = ko.observable("hello");
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

Sample fiddle [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/tz87uLj2/) to check it out .

FYI, you can also use your view model which is also a way to do it .